# I finished my essay yesterday but I (?) it in to the tutor yet

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

I finished my essay yesterday but I (?) it in to the tutor yet.

A.I've given

B.I hadn't given

C.I didn't give

Which is correct?

My dear tutor said the answer had to be B. But I find no correct answer in this question, and I would rather write this sentence as " I finished my essay yesterday. But I haven't given it to the tutor yet."

If I say "I finished my essay yesterday but I hadn't given it in to the tutor yet", have I given the essay in to the tutor?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Somebody [copied](http://ieltssos.blogspot.com/2011/03/drops-of-grammar-check-your-grammar-for_31.html) the question incorrectly. And I hope that linked website got some of the questions wrong as well ... they have a typo of *train* for *trend*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Wow~~~you found the whole set of questions in such a short time! How did you do that?

Comment: I just typed the question into Google.

Comment: Why do you think that option B is incorrect? I am lost a bit here. The past perfect refers to a time earlier than before now. It is used to make it clear that one event happened before another in the past. It does not matter which event is mentioned first - the tense makes it clear which one happened first.
Have a look at this

Comment: The first part of the phrase is: *I finished my essay yesterday...* The act of handing the essay will happen *after* the student has completed the essay, NOT *before*.

Comment: Option B was copied **incorrectly** by someone. See Peter Shor's comment.

Comment: One of the choices is mistranscribed (B. I hadn't given should be I **haven't** given) and it is general reference homework question.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
Do not answer questions which are unclear, out of scope, or already answered many times before. Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: There is a second difficulty with the question, this one involving both the version given here and the version that appears on the site that Peter Shor links to: At least in the form of U.S. English that I use, the expression would not be "...given it in to the tutor yet" but instead either "...turned it in to the tutor yet" or "...given it to the tutor yet." Perhaps "given it in to" is standard in spoken English where you live, but it is certainly not standard everywhere in the English-speaking world.

Comment: As MariLou A indicates, "I finished my essay yesterday but I hadn't given it in to the tutor yet" amounts to saying "When I finished my essay yesterday, I hadn't yet turned it in to my tutor"—which logically is no more surprising than the fact that, when the student started the essay last week, he or she hadn't yet turned it in to the tutor. There is usually little point in saying things like "When I finished step 1, I hadn't yet performed step 2."

Comment: Thank you, Sven Yargs, for explaining it in a relaxed way unlike MariLou A did. After reading your comment, I finally got where I am mistaken. when MariLou A  wrote the comment, I was just like  'what happened and why I see those capitalized in bold words' It is a pity people are like that.

Comment: @DavidJohnson: I'm glad my attempt at an explanation made sense to you, but I must also express my certainty that MariLou A didn't intend to come across as hostile in her remarks. On a flat page, It is quite tempting for a writer to use bold or italics or capitalization to give emphasis where our voices cannot; unfortunately, it's also easy for a reader to misinterpret the sense of those visual markers. But if you stick around for a while on EL&U (which I hope you do), I think you'll find that MariLou A has a good heart and is a tremendously positive force at this site.

Answer (score -1):

I also believe you are right simply because the subject 'I' most probably is talking from a present perspective. If you were that 'I' and you were talking to your friend about that essay, you'd definitely use present perfect simply because that essay would still be in your possession. That's why your choice of tense is logical. 
I guess there is some kind of misconception - many, especially ESL teachers, do think the present time cannot be used in a sentence with a verb in the past time.
Anyways, I guess past perfect could also be used in this sentence (according to English grammar) but such a sentence will sound weird and not real.When you are speaking with another person, you wouldn't say it that way.
By the way, I found an example to back up your point of view (you can even present it to your tutor): [She has grown a foot since she turned nine.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm) Besides, such sentences are used in essays, e.g. [jw essay samples](http://jetwriters.com/brave-new-world-essay/) are full of sentences where past and present time are used in one sentence.

Comment: Option B was copied [incorrectly](http://ieltssos.blogspot.it/2011/03/drops-of-grammar-check-your-grammar-for_31.html) by someone